Model has higher (and closer to 1) $\beta$, but similar $R^2$ and correlation
I have model one which produces prediction $\hat{y_1}$, later I came up with a new model which produces prediction $\hat{y_2}$. I have ground truth $y$. The models are not regression based but they are linear and I want to evaluate them in regression metrics.
If I run $y \sim \beta_1 \hat{y_1}$, $y \sim \beta_2 \hat{y_2}$, I see that $\beta_2 \sim 1$ and $\beta_1 \sim 0.8$. I'd think this means my model 2 is "better scaled".
But if I compute $R2(y, \hat{y_1}) = 1- \frac{\sum (y_t - \hat{y_1}_t )^2 }{\sum y_t^2}$ and $R2(y, \hat{y_2}) = 1- \frac{\sum (y_t - \hat{y_2}_t )^2 }{\sum y_t^2}$ directly (as in I don't try to re-run the regression $y \sim \beta_1 \hat{y_1}$ and get the regression R2. I just directly compute $R2(y, \hat{y_1}) = 1- \frac{\sum (y_t - \hat{y_1}_t )^2 }{\sum y_t^2}$). I see they are roughly equal.
When I compute correlation between $y$ and $\hat{y_1}$ and correlation between $y$ and $\hat{y_2}$, I see they are almost equal too. Note that here correlation might not be square-root of the R2, because my models are not regression based.
What does it tell me about the prediction? I find it a bit surprising. I think a "better scaled" predictor should show up in the regression metrics somewhere?  Why doesn't a "better scaled" regression give me better R2?
[EDIT to elaborate]
Some models provide coefficients in an "exogenous" way. For example in Newtonian law, I have reason to believe $F = ma$, rather than running a regression $F \sim a$, where $a$ can have noise, I might as well just try to estimate $m$, through a scale.
But now that I have estimated $m = f_1(z)$ or $m = f_2(z)$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are two different scales. $z$ are a bunch of other parameters of my scales.  Now I want to plug it back in to measure the goodness of fit $F \sim f_1(z) a$ and $F \sim f_2(z) a $. I can compute the R2 of $F$ and $f(z)$. I can also run regressions $F \sim \beta_1 f(z) a$ and $F \sim \beta_2 f(z) a$.
My question now is, I see $\beta_2$ very close to 1, but $R2( F, f_2(z) a)$ isn't higher than $R2( F, f_1(z) a)$

Make a plot to better see what is going on. You can have a unity coefficient in a linear regression between $y$ and $\hat{y}_1$, but that doesn't mean that the relationship is good.

I don't understand "The models are not regression based but they are linear" and neither "evaluate them in regression metrics".

If your regression $y \sim \hat{y}$ finds a 'better' (lower least squares) solution namely $\hat\beta \hat{y}$ with $\hat\beta \neq 1$, then you need an explanation why the linear model didn't come up with this solution in the first place.

@SextusEmpiricus I added more comments to elaborate the questions in main question. Thanks for the reply

Make those plots of $y$ versus $\hat{y}_1$ and $y$ versus $\hat{y}_2$ they will show you how the coefficient in a linear regression and the correlation or $R^2$ are not the same because of noise.

@zvi besides plotting your data it would be good to actually know the calculated $R^2$ values and rerun it but replace $\Sigma_t y_t^2$ with  $\Sigma_t (y_t - \bar y)^2$ in the denominator. I suspect that $\Sigma_t y_t^2$ is just to large and you should mean center.

The evaluation criteria $R2$ is equivalent to square error $SE=\sum(y-\hat{y})^2$, so I will replace $R2$ with simpler $SE$ for the remaining part.
The $\beta_1=0.8$ is problematic as it shows that the $\hat{y_1}$ systematically deviates from $y$. If there is a predictor $\hat{y_3}=1.25\hat{y_1}+c$ that the $c$ is chosen to minimize the loss $SE$, this new predictor will have $\beta_3=1$ and possibly a lower $SE$.
The easiest thing to do is to draw $y$ against $\hat{y_1}$ and $\hat{y_2}$. Or, create new variable residual $e_i=\hat{y_i}-y$ and plot $\hat{y_i}$ against $e_i$. If there is no pattern for residual, then the model is good. There must be a linear pattern for model 1, so there is some space for improvement. I have no information about the model 2. Assuming the residuals are distributed randomly around 0, it must have a higher variance than model 1. If you draw a horizontal line for model 2 and find that the residual is clearly non-zero, then the way to improve the model is to make it 0.
"Better scaled" doesn't necessarily mean better accuracy. The $\beta$ you describe is more like a diagnosis tool, while $SE$ is a loss function for model accuracy. The $\beta\neq 1$ means the model is mispecified. Model 1 may be potentially better, while model 2 may not.

I think 2nd paragraph is probably the answer, but your 3rd is unclear and has some small mistakes. The small mistakes: You should plot $e_i$ against $\hat y_i$ not $y$ and $e$ should be defined the other way around. The rest is to unclear to judge and I'm not sure it belongs here.
